# Is it possible to center-align content within a div only when the device width is under a certain width in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form which uses Bootstrap in order to do responsive styling. I have the labels for the inputs in one `col-md-6` div, and the inputs themselves in another `col-md-6` div. What I'd like to do is have certain elements left-aligned when in `col-md` and larger, and center-aligned when `col-sm` and below.

Here is a snapshot of what the form looks in full-screen mode:
[image]

and this is what it looks like when the screen is small:

[image]

Ideally I'd want to handle this functionality directly through Bootstrap, but if it's not possible I wasn't sure how to go about doing this from scratch. Any other suggestions on if I'm going about this wrong in the first place would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create a custom `@media` query targeting the device size and working against `form-group` (or `form-control`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* [this is what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/emv9vp9h/embedded/result/) (In the jsFiddle, I made the cut-off at `col-xs-*`, but this can be changed in the `@media` query.)

```css
@media (max-width: 991px){
    .form label {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <form class="form" role="form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <label>Your T-Shirt Size</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option selected="true"></option>
                            <option>Small</option>
                            <option>Medium</option>
                            <option>Large</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <label>Additional Guests</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option selected="true"></option>
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <label>Does anyone in your party require any special accommodations?</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much. I'm fairly new to the `@media` tag so I'll definitely look more into that.

Comment: The `@media` queries are the component that makes up the responsive design (modifying layouts based on screen size (as well as other factors)). They can be quite handy, and are generally supported on most browsers.